# ALT+ENTER, how to detect the newline in NSString?

Tags: cocoa, newline, textfield

in my Cocoa App I have a textfield, where users are supposed to insert a newline by pressing ALT+ENTER. That's fine... when I get the value of it as a NSString and do a NSLog, I actually see that new lines are print.
But when I append the string as part of an html page with appendString and then with loadHTMLString, the new lines are completely ignored in the resulting web page...

Could you kindly give me a suggestion or a documentation link to read? I have really no idea!

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It sounds like you're having problems with your webpage, not with the NSString

Answer (score 1):

Plain newline characters are not rendered by browsers.
Replace the newline characters ( `\n` ) by line break tags ( `<br>` ).

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"]
```

The `<br>` tags will show as newline characters in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the new lines that exist in the string are inserted literally into the html document source. Newlines in html source do not get rendered literally when the html document is rendered. (Imagine if they did; you'd have many, many extra new lines displayed because of all those new line characters separating html tags.)

Instead you should process the raw text entered by the user to produce html source which will render as what the user entered. So you have to break the text up into paragraphs and then insert appropriate `<p></p>` tags.

You can use the NSString method `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` with the option `NSStringEnumerationByParagraphs`. To process each paragraph.

Also, you should to sanitize the data entered by the user. For example you don't want your page to get messed up if the user enters some html tags. Sanatizing the data may be as simple as replacing all the restricted characters in the text with the appropriate html entities, but it depends on what you're doing.